# Cannot send POST request with RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, resttemplate

I have 2 services:

Service Web on http://localhost:8080 and Service Engine on http://localhost:8081

Service Web sends a `POST` request to Service Engine through this code :

```
    String checkWinUrl = customProperties.getEngineUrl() + "/checkWin";
    
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpEntity<GameDto> request = new HttpEntity<>(new GameDto(game));
    
    try {
        ResponseEntity<CheckWinResult> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                checkWinUrl, 
                HttpMethod.POST, 
                request, 
                CheckWinResult.class);
        
        CheckWinResult checkWinResult = response.getBody();
        if (checkWinResult != null && checkWinResult.isWin()) {
            
            Set<Move> result = new HashSet<>();
            for (MoveDto move : checkWinResult.getWinMoves()) {
                result.add(Move.builder().color(GomokuColor.GREEN).columnIndex(move.getColumnIndex()).rowIndex(move.getRowIndex()).build());
            }
            
            return result;
        }
    } catch (RestClientException e) {
        log.error("Error while computing checkWin : " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

---

**RestController**

```
@PostMapping("/checkWin")
public CheckWinResult checkWin(@RequestBody GameDto game) {
    return engineService.checkWin(game);
}
```

and it works fine, Engine Service receives the request properly.

But when Engine Service sends a request to Web Service :

```
    String webAppUrl = customProperties.getWebAppUrl() + "/engineMessage";

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(message.toString());

    restTemplate.exchange(webAppUrl, HttpMethod.POST, request, Void.class);
```

---

**RestController**

```
@PostMapping("/engineMessage")
public void engineMessage(@RequestBody String engineMessage) {
    
    JSONObject jsonMessage = new JSONObject(engineMessage);

    WebSocketMessage webSocketMessage = new WebSocketMessage();
    
    webSocketMessage.setType(MessageType.valueOf(jsonMessage.getString("type")));
    webSocketMessage.setContent(jsonMessage.getString("content"));
    
    webSocketController.sendMessage(webSocketMessage);
}
```

Web Service just never receives the request.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: `RestTemplate` is for `HTTP` Requests, but your Server expects a `WebSocket` connection, those are 2 completely different things:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#websocket-stomp-client

Comment: My server doesn't expect a WebSocket connection, is just prepares a future webSocket connection but the message received comes from a HTTP request. I was thinking maybe because the first HTTP request  is not completed yet, we cannot perform another HTTP request before the current one is not completed ?

Comment: In general a Socket Connection has 2 channels, one to read and one to write.
In `HTTP` you write once and then read once (`Request` -> `Response`).

In `WebSocket` you can `read`/`write` multiple times (`Publish`/`Subscribe`).

So if you send a `HTTP` Request with header `"Upgrade: websocket"` the server should keep both channels open and dispatch the connection to a `WebWocket` handler.